# Chart won't redraw in `onchange` function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I've set up an HTML page that has a C3-powered chart. When the page loads, the chart loads data from a CSV file. There's also a `select` element on my page. When a user changes the `option` in `select`, I want the chart to reload with new data.

Basically, this is my code.

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    bindto: "#chart",
    data: {
        url: dataFile,
        x: "year"
    }
});

document.getElementById("select-element").onchange = function(){
    var newData = [ /* an array of JavaScript objects */ ];
    chart.data.json = newData;
};
```

But when I select an option in the `select` dropdown, nothing changes. How do I fix it so that my chart will load the data from the `newData` array of JS objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all try loading data trough load() and unload() methods, that's the correct way of doing it (can be a json, url, rows or columns) like this example:

```
chart.load({
  columns: [
    ['data1, 100, 200, 150, ...],
    ...
  ],
  unload: ['data2', 'data3']
});
```

Please note that this method is highly documented and should be read:

[Link to load method documentation](https://c3js.org/reference.html#api-load)

To force redraw, you can call flush() method:

```
chart.flush();
```

Comment: In `.load()`, what must I put to load data from an array of JS objects? Or do I need to JSON-ify the array?

Comment: You need to organize the objects to load the JSON object with the desired Columns/Rows/types objects. If you want another approach, you can even load an url (with a csv file, e.g.) as you can see in https://c3js.org/samples/data_load.html.
You can see how to load category data (just another a-little-bit-different way to organize data): https://c3js.org/samples/data_stringx.html there's a lot of examples. I guess you need to look all this examples and chose the one that suits better your data model/organization